# Why An Address Data Is An Entity?

Tags: relational-database, domain-driven-design

I always think that an address data is a value object since it is immutable and its equality is defined by the same data in all fields. For example, a billing address in a part of a payment and a shipping address is a part of an order or a fulfillment. When someone changes her/his address, a new address data is needed. But, every single sample code/application, I have run into, has an address data as an entity, which its DB table has its own ID. It would make a sense if a system wants to keep track of all addresses where all business activities/events occur. I, however, don't see such intention in those sample code/application. Do I miss something in the regard?

Comment: As alluded to in Constantin GALBENU's answer: a database ID does not necessarily indicate that the corresponding domain object is an `Entity`.  It purely facilitates persistence :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't generalize.

Examples are one thing, real world problems are another. You can't say that for all projects one solution fits it all.

I'll give you an example I had in a project conserning aggregate roots.
Logically and legally a subsidiary is an extension of its company, eg. Walmart has its HQ with tax number and everything and subsidiaries without tax number where the actual stuff is sold. Logically, for applying to a goverment funding or something similar, the HQ sends a request for its subsidiary. Here, Walmart HQ is an aggregate root and its subsidiary is a part of an aggregate in funding procedures.
This is a logical example.

What I had is that a subsidiary can legally apply for state funding without the knowledge of HQ! Therefor, HQ is not an aggregate root anymore, but a subsidiary is. It was extremely illogical, but those were the business requirements.

The point is the same with your value object question. Although you can use Address as an example that it is an entity or a value object, it is the requirements of the business that dictate what an address is, and not what is logical.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. With what you said, a billing address and a shipping address have an aggregate root: payment and shipping respectively. Therefore, they shall be value objects.

Answer (score 1):

*Pre-note: there are domains where an address should be an entity, like a mail service; we do not talk about those domains*

From my experience, people tend to implement an address as an entity because of the persistence: it is easier to persist an address as a sub-entity to a relational database than to persist a value object because of the entities ID that act as primary keys in the storage table.

However, there are tactics that permit storing a value object as an database entity but still using it just as a value object, as it should be. Vaughn Vernon shows how to do this in his [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577), *Chapter 6*, sub-chapter *Persisting Value Objects*.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into the subject. http://thepaulrayner.com/persisting-value-objects/